# Using pyVisa with IronPython

Tags: external, ironpython, gpib

The combination pyVisa and IronPython is giving me a hard time currently. I'm trying to communicate with an external device over GPIB using the pyVisa package, from within a script which in turn is written in IronPython.

It is the line

```
visa.ResourceManager()
```

that causes problems. I get the error "expected LP_c_ulong, got NativeArgument", that I can't resolve.

Is there any simple solution to this issue? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In my exeprience is not possible to import directly pyVISA in ironpython, I did someting working using Tektronix dll

```
clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath('C:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\assembly\\GAC_32\TekVISANet\\v4.0_1.1.1.0__7f19bb2a5a9ae6e8\\TekVISANet.dll')
import TekVISANet
```